# Having Issue on Looping Through an Array to Log elements on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can loop to a different element of `sectorArray[]` and log the element, when triggered by button clicks? Right now I have an issue with starting over minus or plus and returning to the start when the function reaches the last element!

```js
var sectorArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
var counter = 0;
$(".plus").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log(sectorArray[counter]);
  counter++;
});
$(".minus").on("click", function(e) {
  counter--;
  console.log(sectorArray[counter]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <button type="button" class="minus">-</button>
    <button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>
```

Comment: So you want it to on the first console.log be a and if you press plus you get b, if you press plus again you get c and if you're at c and press minus you get b, and again you get a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/L56a12mb/6/)

All you need to do is reset the `counter` variable when it reaches out of bounds:

```
var sectorArray = ["a", "b", "c"];
var counter = -1; // start at -1 because we inc/dec before we log

$(".plus").on("click", function(e) {
  // Increment and check if counter is out of bounds
  if(++counter >= sectorArray.length){
    counter = 0;
  }
  console.log(sectorArray[counter]);
});

$(".minus").on("click", function(e) {
  // Decrement and check if counter is out of bounds
  if(--counter < 0){
    counter = sectorArray.length - 1;
  }
  console.log(sectorArray[counter]);
});
```

Comment: Hi Nick and hanks for reply but how come the plus starting from `b`?

Comment: @Behseini It's because you increment the `counter` before you check it for the first time. An easy fix is to move the `counter++` or `counter--` below the `console.log` I'll update my answer with that change!

Comment: @Behseini See my updated answer now - that problem should be resolved :)

Comment: thanks buy there is an issue here. if you 3 times click on + and then on - you will get `undefined` on console!

Comment: @Behseini Ah I see my error - I've fixed it (it works like a charm now!)